# I am a beginner and using pascal. I don't know how to code the output. I am expecting the output to be the result of the function

Tags: output, pascal

I am a beginner and using pascal and i am trying this problem that i attach. What should i do next? I am trying to make this program work by showing the "ayam" Function. But i don't know how to code the rest.

```
function ayam(a, b:integer) : 
integer;
var
  m: integer; 
begin
    readln(a) ;
    readln(b) ;
    readln(m) ;
        begin
            if (b=0) then
              ayam:= 1 else
              ayam:= a * ayam(a, b-1) mod m;
end;
    writeln(ayam);
end;
```

Comment: Please add the rest of the code of your program and say what you are expecting its output to be.

Comment: What do you mean by the rest of the code? (I'm sorry i'm a total beginner). And i think that's all the code that i am trying to make. Did it miss or lack something? I'm expecting the output to be the result of function "ayam". The input is whatever number the user choose (a, b, and m).

Comment: I had a feeling you might ask what I meant by the "rest of the code" because the way you have written your `ayam` function it looks like you think that is all you need when, in fact, it isn't.  I will post you an answer later today that should show you what else you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I should say is that when a question is to do with coursework, as is obviously the case here, there is an unwritten convention that we do not write an answer which simply does your programming task for you.  So in the following, I have not commented on whether the code inside your `ayam` function actually correctly implements what is required - that is for you to do.

Secondly, you did not say which Pascal implementation you are using.  I have written the code of this answer in Lazarus, the IDE for FreePascal (aka FPC), which is the best of the freeware Pascal implementations currently available.

The first thing to do with your code is to re-format it the way it should be formatted,
using indentation of statements to reflect the structure of the steps you are
trying to code.  Basically, your eye should be able to follow the code structure
as easily as possible.  This gives something like this:

```
function ayam(a, b:integer) : integer;
var
  m: integer;
begin
  readln(a) ;
  readln(b) ;
  readln(m) ;
  begin
    if (b=0) then
      ayam:= 1
    else
      ayam:= a * ayam(a, b-1) mod m;
  end;
  writeln(ayam);
end;
```

With that change made, it is pretty obvious that there is something wrong with
the logic of your code, because `a` and `b` are declared as input variables to
the `ayam` function but your code actually reads in their values via the
`readln` statements **inside** the function.  This is what made me think that you think
you have done all that's necessary to write your program.  In fact, you have not.  What you are missing
is some code which sets up the input parameters `a` and `b` (and `m`, see below) in some way and then
invokes your `ayam` function to calculate its value and then does something with
the result.   At the moment, your code simply **defines** `ayam` but takes no steps
to use it.  So, to get your `ayam` function to do anything, you need to write a complete
Pascal program that uses it.  Something like this:

```
program ayamprogram;

{ the following declares some variables for the program to use }
var
  varA,
  varB,
  varM,
  varResult : Integer;

{ next, we define the ayam function }
function ayam(a, b, m:integer) : integer;
begin
  begin
    if (b=0) then
      ayam:= 1
    else
      ayam:= a * ayam(a, b-1, m) mod m;
  end;
end;

{ now we write the code of the program, which reads in the values to be
  used by ayam, then invokes ("calls") ayam to calculate its value and
  assign its value to the varResult variable and then outputs the calculated
  result using the writeln statement
}
begin
  { this is the code of the program }

  readln(varA);
  readln(varB);
  readln(varM);

  varResult := ayam(varA, varB, varM);

  writeln('function ayam evaluates to ', varResult);

  readln;  { this causes the program to pause so you can see the result of the writeln statement }
end.  { end of program }
```

Note that I have used different variable names for the variables which are supplied to `ayam`, varA, varB, varM, from the variable names used inside `ayam` to avoid confusion between them.

Note also that as it is bad practice to read user input inside an executing function, the value to be used for M is read in before `ayam` is called and is supplied to `ayam` as a third parameter.

A point you need to consider regarding the expression

```
ayam:= a * ayam(a, b-1, m) mod m
```

is whether the `mod m` should operate on the value of `ayam(a, b-1, m)` or on the entire expression including the `a *` as well; if so, parentheses can enforce the evaluation order you need, by writing

```
ayam:= (a * ayam(a, b-1, m)) mod m
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation! So i start to write everything again by using your example. I rewrite everything and also trying to understand the structure of it. But after i've done writing the code. It says "either too few or too many arguments are being passed to function ayam". Why is that? I have double check to make sure that everythings are the same as yours

Comment: Sorry, the reason for that error is that I forgot to correct the recursive call to `ayam` where it said ` ayam:= a * ayam(a, b-1) mod m` and the reason the compiler is complaining is that the call to `ayam` should include the third parameter, `m`, so that line should be ` ayam:= a * ayam(a, b-1, m) mod m`.